# Use tap() instead of map() RxJS and Angular

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have a login guard which basically check if the user il logged in. If he is logged, it skips the login and go to home page. I wrote this code, and this works:

```typescript
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.store.select(fromApp.isAuthenticated)
        .pipe(take(1),
            map(isAuthenticated => {
                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            })
        )
}
```

Now, since I don't have to change or edit the output data (isAuthenticated boolean), I thought: well, why don't use tap operator? So, I re-write my code:

```typescript
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.store.select(fromApp.isAuthenticated)
        .pipe(take(1),
   HERE------> tap(isAuthenticated => {   <------ HERE
                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            })
        )
}
```

Then I went to Chrome, and I saw black page and this was the case:

- I open the app
- I'm not logged in
- The url becomes http://localhost:4200/#/ instead of
  http://localhost:4200/#/login, result: blank page
- If I try to go manually in http://localhost:4200/#/login, it stays in
  that page but I see a blank page
- If I try to go home, it redirects on http://localhost:4200/#/ instead
  of http://localhost:4200/#/login

In any case, I see blank page. So, I went in debug and I noticed that it correctly jump inside the if/else block... so, why tap() is breaking the app?

Comment: "tap" not modified the response. "tap", when the subscribe was finished called execute the acction

Comment: But in theory I should use map if I have to modify the value (isAuthenticated)... isn't it?

Comment: In your code in tap, the return it's unnecessary, but the navigate must be correct

Comment: Did you mean the 'return false/true'? is it unnecessary in the 'map' code too?

Comment: But you *do* change or edit the output data in the map version; you invert the boolean.

Comment: I inverted the boolean? What do you mean?

Comment: In the case where isAuthenticated was initially truthy the map callback returned false, and vice versa. There's no point returning from a tap callback, but you should still ensure you get the same output overall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) is the signature of `canActivate`:

```typescript
interface CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

`canActivate` must either return `boolean` or `Promise`. Therefore you must `map` it and return a `boolean` or `Promise`. `tap` will not do the trick.

Comment: but you may seperate the routing into a tap (after the map) :-)

Comment: That doesn't mean you *must* map it; what does store.select return? If that's already an observable of boolean then a tap is fine. I think it's a *value* problem, not a *type* problem.

Comment: So tap just continue the stream withouth return nothing? @JanRecker lol glad to see your help again :D what do you mean? Do dispatch a new action which works with tap() and manages the routing?

Comment: tap will not modify the stream, it is used to put side effects in it, such as console logs for example (for trouble shooting purpose).

Comment: Hi again :-) 
in my personal rxjs religion (as is said, very personal) i extract everything that is not altering the stream into "taps". My reason is, that i like "intentions" of code snippets. The intention of "map" is to alter the stream, the intention of tap is to handle sideeffects. There is no need do it like that, but i find it more readable. 
About the Action, i like the idea. if you have any clean ups to do, the action can nicely handle it. If not, ... The new URL should be a state change by itself.

Answer (score 3):

The guard `canActivate` has to return an `Observable<boolean>` in order for the Angular guard mechanism to work.

Using `map` allows you to define a return which is different from what you get from `isAuthenticated`, and this probably explains what you see.

In your first version `canActivate` acutally returns an `Observable<boolean>` - in the second case it returns this `this.store.select(fromApp.isAuthenticated).pipe(take(1))` , and probably it is not what you want.

Comment: Same comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205810/use-tap-instead-of-map-rxjs-and-angular/51205938#comment89393100_51205938